Why 'If $rad(G)≥3$ then $rad(\bar G)\leq 2$?
I was reading a proof about radius of self-complementory graph and I stumbled across statement that "if $rad(G)≥3$ then $rad(\bar G)\leq 2$ and that if $diam(G)≥3$ then $diam(\bar G)\leq 3$. I couldn't find similar statements anywhere else. Is that a common-sense kind of thing? Or is there a proof? Is it a theorem? I tried to draw a couple of graphs, verified that it's in fact true but I'd appreciate any extra info.
Source of question: Prove that a self-complementary graph has radius $2$ and diameter $2$ or $3$
Thank you for clarification.

I don’t quite understand what’s the question. Isn’t it proved following your link? What’s the difference between your question and that question?

@Aig, the question deals with the radius of self-complementary graph but the person who asked the questions says that 'we know that if $rad(G) ≥ 3$ then the complement has radius ≤2." And this fact is then used to prove the rest but where does the fact come from? Is it correct to assume that the radius of complement is always smaller than the radius of the graph?

It's definitely not obvious, but it is fairly simple to prove. In both cases, if $\text{rad}(G) \geq 3$ or $\text{diam}(G) \geq 3$, then there are some two vertices $x,y$ at distance $\geq 3$, so without any path of length $1$ or $2$ between them. So no vertex can have an edge to both $x$ and $y$. Now consider what that means for the complement.
